# Get the Sum of the top X values from a single Row (Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I struggling to get the sum total of the top X values for a Row.

Let say top 3 in this case.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | Mary | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 |

So the total of the top **3** values would be

| name | Total |
| --- | --- |
| John | 9 |
| Mary | 11 |

I can get a single LARGE number but can't figure out how to get the top 5 in the row (and then sum). Most examples have the values in COLS but my data is in ROWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Sum of top 5 in a row:*

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(LARGE(A1:1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), 0))
```

**Rundown of this formula:**

- Use the array notation to denote the first, second, third, fourth and fifth highest in the row with `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
- Set this array as the `n` parameter for a `LARGE` formula, with the row as the `range` parameter
- If the LARGE throws an error for whatever reason, return the value `0` for that value of `n`
- `SUM` all answers
- Wrap inside an `ARRAYFORMULA` so that `LARGE` gets all array values and not just the first.

#### References:

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- [LARGE - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094008?hl=en)
- [IFERROR - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [SUM - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks you, 99% there. This formula works perfect, however, 
I just noticed that unless there is a value in the cell, there is an error. 
ie. If the cell is empty, I thought it would interpret this as a 0.
Is there anything I can update ?

Comment: @DevilDog Updated to include IFERROR, see if that helps?